# Is it possible to run a confirmatory message once jersey app is installed on server and running?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I have to run a simple task every few minutes in my Jersey app but I dont want to invoke it using a service so I want it to run automatically after my app is installed on the server. The idea is once the app is installed the process should be running.

Is this possible or are there better options?,

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom listener class by implementing `ServletContextListener`, which run your code before the web application is started.

You can find this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) helpful for further details.

Comment: Thanks @Rohan this works perfectly. I wonder why someone downvoted my question without explanation though. ( I will reserve  my comments about them )